# Flutter, TextFormField Suffix Widget position like youtube

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

It seems to have been an issue for a long time, is there still no solution?

If you set suffixIcon: it will automatically center when MaxLines is 3. (so it locates at 2nd line)

However, the downside of this is that the top and bottom padding values are a problem.

Therefore, customizing it is easier to just use suffix: to make it a widget.

but with suffix:

When I do

```
Container(child:Text("Test button"))....
```

The button height is completely lengthened (by the length of max lines)

I just want to implement like youtube comment suffix icon

At first, it's in the top right corner, and whenever the line changes, I want the send Icon to go down too. Is there still no way? Flutter?

Comment: Question is positing suffixIcon while having multiple line?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yup, when you open the youtube app, when do typing comments, if change the lines, then also suffix also going down.. but in flutter it is can not be done I guess

Comment: well there might be some ways to do a thing.  So you like to make align a button at bottom beside TextFiled(based on line Input)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yah yah!! Exactly!!! is there a way to achieve this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Row widget with `CrossAxisAlignment.end`

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: TextFormField(
        maxLines: 4,
        minLines: 1,
      ),
    ),
    Icon(Icons.abc) // padding more decoration if needed
  ],
),
```

Comment: I am gonna try now and let you know!! thanks!!

Comment: It is working I have been looking for this so long time thanks.. It was not complicated omg.. I think I'm more confused because of InputDecoration's suffix: and suffixIcon: . Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help, You can find more about [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)